How to find the first derivatives of this quadratic function w.r.t. a vector?
There is a quadratic-like function:
$$
f(\theta) = \boldsymbol{w}(\theta)^{\mathrm{H}}\boldsymbol{B}(\theta)\boldsymbol{w}(\theta)
$$
where $\theta \in \mathbb{C} ^{N\times 1}$ is the column vector that needs to be derived, $\boldsymbol{B} (\theta) \in \mathbb{C} ^{M\times M}$ is a matrix which is concerned with $\theta$. $\boldsymbol{w}(\theta) \in \mathbb{C} ^{M\times 1}$ is a column vector about $\theta$.
How to derive the partial derivatives of this function $f(\theta)$ w.r.t. $\theta$?
I didn't find any answer to this topic in this stack exchange, so I hope you can leave a valuable comment if you have any good suggestions or if it's not clearly expressed from me.
Thanks in advance!

So with $\theta = (\theta_1,\dotsc,\theta_M)$ you want to calculate $\partial/\partial\theta_i$?

@NicholasTodoroff, Yes

Maybe $\theta$ is $N$ dimensional column vector which $N\ne M$, I want to find the partial derivatives of $\frac{\partial f\left( \theta \right)}{\partial \theta}$. Thanks!

$
\def\C#1{{\mathbb C}^{#1}}
\def\R#1{{\mathbb R}^{#1}}
\def\t{\theta}
\def\tk{\t_k}
\def\k{\otimes}
\def\o{{\tt1}}
\def\lR#1{\Big(#1\Big)}
\def\bR#1{\Big[#1\Big]}
\def\BR#1{\left[#1\right]}
\def\LR#1{\left(#1\right)}
\def\op#1{\operatorname{#1}}
\def\trace#1{\op{Tr}\LR{#1}}
\def\frob#1{\left\| #1 \right\|_F}
\def\q{\quad}      \def\qq{\qquad}
\def\qif{\q\iff\q} \def\qiq{\q\implies\q}
\def\p{\partial}   \def\grad#1#2{\frac{\p #1}{\p #2}}
\def\c#1{\color{red}{#1}}
\def\CLR#1{\c{\LR{#1}}}
\def\fracLR#1#2{\LR{\frac{#1}{#2}}}
\def\gradLR#1#2{\LR{\grad{#1}{#2}}}
$First
calculate the differential of the function
$$\eqalign{
f &= w^HBw \\
df &= \c{dw^H}\,Bw \;+\; w^H\,\c{dB}\;w \;+\; w^HB\;\c{dw} \qq\qq\q
}$$
and thence the derivative with respect to the $k^{th}$ component of $\t$
$$\eqalign{
\grad{f}{\tk}
 &= \c{\gradLR{w^H}\tk}Bw\;+\;w^H\c{\gradLR B\tk}w\;+\;w^HB\c{\gradLR w\tk}\\
}$$
Conjugation leads to three other derivatives that you might wish to consider
$$\eqalign{
\grad{f^*}{\tk} \qq \grad{f}{\tk^*} \qq \grad{f^*}{\tk^*}
}$$
Update
Per your first comment, if you vectorize the matrix $\big({\rm vec}(B)=b\big)$ then the problematic term can be handled as
$$\eqalign{
d\lambda
 &= w^H\,dB\:w
  = (w^*w^T):dB
  = (w\k w^*):db \\
 &= (w\k w^*):\gradLR{b}{\t}d\t
  = \gradLR{b}{\t}^T(w\k w^*): d\t \\
\frac{d\lambda}{d\t}
 &= \gradLR{b}{\t}^T(w\k w^*) \\
}$$
where the Kronecker product is denoted by $\k$
and the colon product is defined as
$$\eqalign{
B:A = A:B = {\rm trace}\LR{A^TB}, \qq A:A^* = \big\|A\big\|^2_F  \\
}$$
Then the full suite of gradients look like
$$\eqalign{
\def\G{\grad}
\def\GR{\gradLR}
\G{f}{\t}
 &=\; \GR{w^*}{\t}^TBw
 &+\; \GR{b}{\t}^T(w\k w^*)
 &+\; \GR{w}{\t}^TB^Tw^* \\
\G{f^*}{\t^*} &=\; \GR{f}{\t}^* \\
\G{f^*}{\t}
 &=\; \GR{w}{\t}^TB^*w^*
 &+\; \GR{b^*}{\t}^T(w^*\k w)\:
 &+\; \GR{w^*}{\t}^TB^Hw \\
\G{f}{\t^*} &=\: \GR{f^*}{\t}^* \\
}$$

That's what I was thinking, but for this expression $\frac{\partial \boldsymbol{B}\left( \theta \right)}{\partial \theta}$ is it in tensor structure? Can it be expressed in $vec$? I would prefer to express it in $vec$-form, do you know how to do it?@greg

@JiaqiLee Without knowledge of the actual $B(\theta),,w(\theta)$ functions this answer is the best I can do. It's usually possible to avoid tensor-valued gradients in Matrix Calculus problems. You might also want to research Wirtinger derivatives. See this post for example of how this idea can be used.

Thank you very much for your advice, your comment has helped me a lot and I will read your link carefully! @greg

I really appreciate you spending your valuable time on answering my question, and I have followed your line of thought and have successfully simplified the similar form using the properties of $vec$ and Kronecker product! Have a nice life! @greg
Thank you very much again!

Chain rule still holds for complex domain functions. Fix $k \in 1, \ldots, N$. We have :
\begin{equation*}
\frac{\partial}{\partial \theta_k}f(\theta) = 
\frac{\partial}{\partial \theta_k}\sum_{i=1}^M \sum_{j=1}^M w_i(\theta)w_j(\theta)B_{ij}(\theta) 
= \sum_{i=1}^M \sum_{j=1}^M (\frac{\partial w_i}{\partial \theta_k}(\theta) w_j(\theta)B_{ij}(\theta) + w_i(\theta) \frac{\partial w_j}{\partial \theta_k}(\theta) B_{ij}(\theta)  + w_i(\theta)w_j(\theta) \frac{\partial B_{ij}}{\partial \theta_k}(\theta) )
\end{equation*}
Now the first two terms are equal. So we can simplify the result as :
\begin{equation*}
\frac{\partial}{\partial \theta_k}f(\theta) = 
2\sum_{i=1}^M \sum_{j=1}^M \frac{\partial w_i}{\partial \theta_k}(\theta) w_j(\theta)B_{ij}(\theta)  +  \sum_{i=1}^M \sum_{j=1}^Mw_i(\theta)w_j(\theta) \frac{\partial B_{ij}}{\partial \theta_k}(\theta) 
\end{equation*}
The last term is still a quadratic form. You can introduce notations to write this in shorter ways.

$B$ was not stated to be symmetric. You need to replace $B$ with its symmetrization $B'{ij} = \frac12(B{ij} + B_{ji})$ for your last expression to be valid. Your very first expression (and all subsequent expressions) are also incorrect as they are missing missing the Hermitian conjugate on the first $w$.

Thank you for your useful advice!@温泽海;
You are exactly right, $B$ here is not necessarily symmetrical or Hermitian. @NicholasTodoroff
